# Include a specific post to the query_posts and remove it if it is already in the returned list

Tags: php, custom-taxonomy, query-posts, featured-post

Bare with me. Firstly, here is my whole script for my featured slider articles:

```
<div id="featured" class="<?php if ( $responsive ) echo 'flexslider' . $featured_auto_class; else echo 'et_cycle'; ?>">
<a id="left-arrow" href="#"><?php esc_html_e('Previous','Aggregate'); ?></a>
<a id="right-arrow" href="#"><?php esc_html_e('Next','Aggregate'); ?></a>

<?php if ( $responsive ) { ?>
    <ul class="slides">
<?php } else { ?>
    <div id="slides">
<?php } ?>
<?php global $ids;
$ids = array();
$arr = array();
$i=0;

$featured_cat = get_option('aggregate_feat_cat');
$featured_num = (int) get_option('aggregate_featured_num');

if (get_option('aggregate_use_pages') == 'false') query_posts("showposts=$featured_num&top=billboard"); // set which slug in custom taxonomy TOP it should filter
else {
    global $pages_number;

    if (get_option('aggregate_feat_pages') <> '') $featured_num = count(get_option('aggregate_feat_pages'));
    else $featured_num = $pages_number;

    query_posts(array
    ('post_type' => 'page',
        'orderby' => 'menu_order',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'post__in' => (array) get_option('aggregate_feat_pages'),
        'showposts' => (int) $featured_num
    ));
} ?>
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) :
    global $post;
    if (!$first_time) // START custom first post
    {
        $post_id = 105; // This is the ID of the first post to be displayed on slider
        $post = get_post($post_id);
        $first_time = 1;
    }
    else the_post(); // END custom first post
    ?>
    <?php if ( $responsive ) { ?>
            <li class="slide">
        <?php } else { ?>
            <div class="slide">
        <?php } ?>
    <?php
    $width = $responsive ? 960 : 958;
    $height = 340;
    $small_width = 95;
    $small_height = 54;
    $titletext = get_the_title();

    $thumbnail = get_thumbnail($width,$height,'',$titletext,$titletext,false,'Featured');

    $arr[$i]['thumbnail'] = get_thumbnail($small_width,$small_height,'',$titletext,$titletext,false,'Small');
    $arr[$i]['titletext'] = $titletext;

    $thumb = $thumbnail["thumb"];
    print_thumbnail($thumb, $thumbnail["use_timthumb"], $titletext, $width, $height, ''); ?>
    <div class="featured-top-shadow"></div>
    <div class="featured-bottom-shadow feat<?php $category = get_the_category(); echo $category[0]->category_nicename; ?>"></div>
    <div class="featured-description">
        <div class="feat_desc">
            <h2 class="featured-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
            <p><?php $excerpt = get_the_excerpt(); echo string_limit_words($excerpt,20); ?></p>
        </div>
    </div> <!-- end .description -->
    <?php if ( $responsive ) { ?>
            </li> <!-- end .slide -->
    <?php } else { ?>
            </div> <!-- end .slide -->
    <?php } ?>
    <?php $ids[] = $post->ID; $i++; endwhile; endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>
<?php if ( $responsive ) { ?>
    </ul> <!-- end .slides -->
<?php } else { ?>
</div> <!-- end #slides -->
<?php } ?>
</div> <!-- end #featured -->
```

It `query_posts` a set amount of posts from the custom taxonomy `top=billboard`. The following part of the code:

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) :
    global $post;
    if (!$first_time) // START custom first post
    {
        $post_id = 105; // This is the ID of the first post to be displayed on slider
        $post = get_post($post_id);
        $first_time = 1;
    }
    else the_post(); // END custom first post
    ?>
```

Adds the post ID `105` to the first post of the returned list. This allows me to control which post is displayed first. **The problem is**: If post ID `105` is already included in the custom taxonomy `top=billboard`, then it will appear twice in the list... so once because it was added in the above `custom first post` script, and once because it was added in the custom taxonomy `top=billboard`.

How do I adjust my code so that if post ID `105` exists in custom taxonomy `top=billboard`, then it should **not** appear twice (only as the first post).

Comment: You could do with some re-formatting, the code is hard to read, so many unnecessary opening and closing tags e.g. <?php hello(); ?> <?php world(); ?> should be written as <?php hello(); world(); ?>

Comment: Also I cannot strongly recommend enough that you abandon all use of `query_posts`, you will save yourself hundreds of hours of pain and misery by exorcising that function from your code. Learn to hate it with the fire of a hundred suns. Instead use `WP_Query` and `get_posts`. See here: http://www.slideshare.net/andrewnacin/you-dont-know-query-wordcamp-netherlands-2012

Comment: Thank you, I am a learning programmer and yes, it has given me some pain indeed. Although with respect, this does not answer my question.

Comment: @ChristineCooper, it doesn't answer the Q, but gives a good hint, what if you modify the code, same results?

Comment: Modify my code with what? I am not entirely sure what your question is.

Comment: That wasn't my answer, rather it was advice, a comment, for an actual solution, refer to my answer posted below. If you indent and stick to a strict formatting standard, it becomes habit, and certain types of error stick out like a sore thumb visually like they've got alarm bells all over them. It makes life a lot easier. Look at PHP Tidy and HTML Tidy tools, they can automatically do a lot of the formatting for you

Answer (score 1):

Okay so I tried to read your code, and failed, and reformatted it as it's currently unreadable, and any errors are obscured by this unreadability. I cannot stress the importance of indenting correctly and following a standardised formatting for making your life infinitely easier:

```
<?php
$featured_class = 'et_cycle';
$tag = 'ul';
$attr = 'class';
if($responsive){
    $featured_class = 'flexslider' . $featured_auto_class;
    $tag = 'div';
    $attr = 'id';
}

?>
<div id="featured" class="<?php echo $featured_class; ?>">
    <a id="left-arrow" href="#"><?php esc_html_e( 'Previous', 'Aggregate' ); ?></a>
    <a id="right-arrow" href="#"><?php esc_html_e( 'Next', 'Aggregate' ); ?></a>
    <?php


    echo '<'.$tag.' '.$attr.'="slides">';

    global $ids;
    $ids = array();
    $arr = array();
    $i=0;

    $featured_cat = get_option( 'aggregate_feat_cat' );
    $featured_num = (int) get_option( 'aggregate_featured_num' );

    $query_args = array();
    if ( get_option( 'aggregate_use_pages' ) == 'false' ){
        // set which slug in custom taxonomy TOP it should filter
        $query_args = array(
            'showposts' => $featured_num,
            'top' => 'billboard'
        );
    }else {
        global $pages_number;

        if ( get_option( 'aggregate_feat_pages' ) <> '' ){
            $featured_num = count( get_option( 'aggregate_feat_pages' ) );
        } else{
            $featured_num = $pages_number;
        }
        query_args = array(
                'post_type' => 'page',
                'orderby' => 'menu_order',
                'order' => 'ASC',
                'post__in' => (array) get_option( 'aggregate_feat_pages' ),
                'showposts' => (int) $featured_num
        );
    }

    // needs to die, use WP_Query instead
    query_posts($query_args);


    if ( have_posts() ) {
        while ( have_posts() ) {
            global $post;
            // START custom first post
            if ( !$first_time ) {
                $post_id = 105; // This is the ID of the first post to be displayed on slider
                $post = get_post( $post_id );
                $first_time = 1;
            }else{
                the_post(); // END custom first post
            }
            if ( $responsive ) {
                echo '<li';
            }else {
                echo '<div';
            }
            echo ' class="slide">';
            $width = $responsive ? 960 : 958;
            $height = 340;
            $small_width = 95;
            $small_height = 54;
            $titletext = get_the_title();

            $thumbnail = get_thumbnail( $width, $height, '', $titletext, $titletext, false, 'Featured' );

            $arr[$i]['thumbnail'] = get_thumbnail( $small_width, $small_height, '', $titletext, $titletext, false, 'Small' );
            $arr[$i]['titletext'] = $titletext;

            $thumb = $thumbnail["thumb"];
            print_thumbnail( $thumb, $thumbnail["use_timthumb"], $titletext, $width, $height, '' );
            ?>
            <div class="featured-top-shadow"></div>
            <div class="featured-bottom-shadow feat<?php $category = get_the_category(); echo $category[0]->category_nicename; ?>"></div>
            <div class="featured-description">
                <div class="feat_desc">
                    <h2 class="featured-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                    <p><?php $excerpt = get_the_excerpt(); echo string_limit_words( $excerpt, 20 ); ?></p>
                </div>
            </div> <!-- end .description -->
                <?php if ( $responsive ) { ?>
                        </li> <!-- end .slide -->
                <?php } else { ?>
                        </div> <!-- end .slide -->
                <?php } ?>
                <?php $ids[] = $post->ID; $i++;
        }
    }

    wp_reset_query();
    echo '</'.$tag.'>';
    ?>
</div> <!-- end #featured -->
```

You'll notice i made some simplifications and swapped out the if statements so they all use `{}` rather than a muddle of shorthand and standard.

There are a number of issues here, the one at the end being wp_reset_query, and the biggest alarm bell being the use of `query_posts`.

I strongly recommend you never use query_posts and instead use either `WP_Query` or `get_posts`.

The culprit here is your loop:

```
        while ( have_posts() ) {
            global $post;
            // START custom first post
            if ( !$first_time ) {
                $post_id = 105; // This is the ID of the first post to be displayed on slider
                $post = get_post( $post_id );
                $first_time = 1;
            }else{
                the_post(); // END custom first post
            }
```

Here we see the beginning of your post loop, it checks if there are additional posts, then calls `the_post` to advance forwards.

When the first post happens however, you don't call `the_post`, so the loop fails to advance. This is not how a loop should work, you should **always** call `the_post` regardless.

Instead, I'd suggest you specify in your query not to include the post 105. ( I would also avoid hardcoding the post ID, it may not always be a 105 ).

So, to start with, use the `post__not_in` parameter on your query, e.g.:

```
$query_args['post__not_in'] = array(105);
```

Comment: I tested your cleaned up code and it returned a `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '='` error. Nonetheless, can you please elaborate on where I add the `$query_args['post__not_in'] = array(105);`? Thank you for the reply.

Comment: If you look at my modified version of your code, instead of 2 query_posts calls, I instead create an array and pass it into query_posts, filling it with different things depending on the if statement. You will want to insert before the query posts call. Think of query_args as a shopping list, then imagine what would happen if you asked for stuff after WordPress had gone out to get it ( e.g. does it make sense to say "hey you've just come back from the shop, I'd like you to get some milk while you're there" )

Comment: that parse error, I cant see where it would be coming from, can you provide more information? like what's the line of code is the error on?

Comment: Thank you for the elaboration. The error is related to line 43. I should have stated that in my previous comment, apologies.

Comment: which line is that? I don't know where you've copy pasted my code to, if you can find line 43 and let me know what it says?

Answer (score 0):

i use `pre_get_posts`. example:

```
add_action('pre_get_posts','search_filterr');function search_filterr($query) {
    if ( !is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() )   {
        if ( $query->is_search ) { //$query->is_category or etc...except is_page()
            $arrs[]='post';
            $arrs[]='page';
            $arrs[]='my_carss';
            $query->set('post_type',  $arrs );
        }
    }
}
```